# how to set responsive background-image of element using css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

whenever I set the `background-image`for an `<a>` , it always requires to specify the width and height in the stylesheet file. which make the urlimage not responsive, and when I try the solutions I found here in another questions such as
`background-size: cover;
    background-color: transparent;`

or using class row and specify col or using `max-height` and `max-width` the image disappears.

Here is my current code which is not responsive at all:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="position:absolute; bottom:50px;">
    <a class="urlImg" href="~/Home/Wall"></a>
</div>
```

and for the .css file

```
.urlImg {
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 height:243px; 
 width:1022px;
 display:block; 
 background-image:url(../img/2.2.png);

} 

.urlImg:hover {
     background-image:url(../img/2.1.png);

} 

.urlImg:active {
     background-image:url(../img/2.3.png);

} 

.urlImg:visited {
     background-image:url(../img/2.2.png);

}
```

how to make this urlimages responsive?

Comment: try using `width: 100%; height: 100%` and then setting `background-size: cover;`

Comment: @zeropublix tried that also but disappeared.. and i think that because I has a backgorund images slide automatically, the element background looks like it doesn't float over them

Comment: make a fiddle so that we can try that out.

Comment: it now looks like that... still not displayed
`.urlImg {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    display:inline-block; 
    background-image:url(../img/2.2.png);
} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a fiddle to make it more clear

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ywzwk1z0/

```
.container-fluid{
  height:50%;
  width:50%;
}
```

Also added `background-size:contain;`